# Qt C++ simple app beginners questions

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I`m in need of creating ui for a program written in c++. As I am a total newbie in Qt I need some help. The original program is quite long so I will just describe what I need.   Program in console version just asks user for a row of numeric data and calculates solution. I have designed a UI in Qt   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hox2u.jpg and    and I want to use my old program as a function in which input data are gathered from UI and then start button launches calculation and returns the solution.
To make it easy how to connect for example an easy function (c * b+c) where inputs are values gathered from comboboxes and sliders made in design mode and how to launch that function by button and  return the solution?

Comment: This question is probably too broad for stackoverflow. Do a simple Qt tutorial to see how signals + slots work, then set up your calculation function as a slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very rough guess, but I believe you want to reuse your previous code without copy pasting the new UI code .

For that you should use static or dynamic linkage. Set your old program to be compiled as a library and link it to your project.

Find tutorials online on how to do that.

Search for static linkage, dynamic linkage, dynamic loading and shared libraries.